# How can i print my webpage directly without getting print dialogue box using asp.net?

Tags: c#, printing

How can i print my webpage directly without getting print dialogue box using asp.net and c#.net
my code is

```
window.frames['iFramePdf'].print();
```

i have click the print button generate the pdf file and display the iframe and automatically print that pdf file without print dialogue box please help me any one

Thank u
hemanth

Comment: Drive-by printing is your goal?

Answer (score 2):

There is usually no way to do that from a browser, in order to prevent malicious pages from printing page upon page of (say) pure black. Accept the popup dialog, or don't use html.

ASP.NET doesn't come into it at all, as this is (presumably) client-side.

Another approach, of course, is to use a dedicated service to pull down pages, and print from the service (actually, my last employer used to use this approach for lots of print runs; it works fine) - but this then is not a browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can bypass the print dialog box using activeX control and VBscript.

```
<script language='VBScript'>
Sub Print()
   OLECMDID_PRINT = 6
   OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2
   OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER = 1
   call WB.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER,1)
End Sub
document.write "<object ID='WB' WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0 CLASSID='CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-   A96B-00C04FD705A2'></object>"
</script>
```

this replaces the default print function.  then you can trigger the print by using javascript

```
window.print();
```

Comment: Even if that works (which it won't in anything but IE) that's an ugly solution.